# Redshift for local testing

Tags: java, apache-spark-sql, amazon-redshift

For local query testing can we have an embedded redshift instance possibly in-memory one? I am using java and I don't want to use docker instance running locally.
Even if it is mocked one, I would be fine.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you asking how to spin up a local Redshift instance? Here is what is Redshift https://aws.amazon.com/redshift/

Answer (score 2):

The answer of this question is `NO`, you can't have locally embedded `Redshift`.
Though I have never thought before, getting a tricky idea while writing this answer, I think you could have `PostgreSQL` embedded local database, though there are lot of differences between `Redshift` v/s `PostgreSQL`, but there are [similarities](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_redshift-and-postgres-sql.html) as well. So for testing/development purpose, I think it could solve some of your problems, but not 100%. And you could use `PostgreSQL` `JDBC` driver locally and change it to `Redshift` `JDBC` driver in `AWS` environment.

Similarity and diffrencess between `PostgreSQL` vs `Redshift` refer following and beware of some of `SQL semantics`.

1. [Ref One](https://db-engines.com/en/system/Amazon+Redshift%3BPostgreSQL)
2. [Ref Two](https://www.flydata.com/blog/redshift-vs-postgres/)
3. [Ref Three](https://www.stitchdata.com/blog/how-redshift-differs-from-postgresql/)
4. [Ref Four](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_redshift-and-postgres-sql.html)

I hope this give you some direction, if you have specific questions, please comment, I would refocus my answer.